# ExtJS 4.2 apply DateField to input form field

Tags: extjs, extjs4, datefield

I am trying to convert my application from 3.1 to 4.2 and can't seem to figure out what needs to be modified in place of the 'applyto'. I have tried variations of renderto and contentel but can't seem to figure it out. With 4.2 nothing seems to happen. No errors in firebug...

Ext 3.1 code that works

```
 cust_datepicker = function(){
     var els=Ext.select("input.date-picker",true);
     els.each(function(el) {
         new Ext.form.DateField({
             applyto: el.id
             ,format: 'Y-m-d'
             ,altFormats: 'j|j/n|j/n/y|j/n/Y|j-M|j-M-y|j-M-Y'
             ,editable: false
             ,id : el.id
         });
     }
 )};
 Ext.onReady(function(){
     cust_datepicker();
 });
```

HTML Code:

```html
<form action="xxx/xxx.cgi" method="GET">
<table><tr>
<td><input name="startdate" class="date-picker"/></td>
</tr></table>
</form>
```

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Here something that worked for me with ExtJS 4.2.0.

The solution is to create a Form containing a Field.

HTML :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="here"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var here = document.getElementById('here');
var my_form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: here,
        width: 100,
        bodyStyle: 'border: none; padding: 0px',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldStyle: 'width: 76px;',
            margin: false
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using contentEl property:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-contentEl